# TypeError: Cannot call method "getField" of null User Event

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am receiving an error on a script I just released to production (did not receive error in sandbox testing)

Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getField" of null User Event

-This is strange because from what I can tell it is not causing issues with my solution (it works completely the way it's supposed to.)

- users are not getting this error, only email to myself (script owner) and obviously the execution log
- it happens on old and new transactions, the first time a user loads the page.
- The error happens on the first field the script tries to get regardless of which one it is.
- It only happens on certain transactions, and I cannot find the correlation.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/url', 'N/runtime', 'N/search'],

function(record, serverWidget, url, runtime, search) {
    function beforeLoad(context){
        var form = context.form;
        var sublist = form.getSublist({
            id : 'item'
        });

        var recObj = context.newRecord
        var recId = recObj.id;
        var currUser = runtime.getCurrentUser();
        var numLines = recObj.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
        var sessionScope = runtime.getCurrentSession().get({  ////remove after debug
            name: 'scope'
        });
        log.debug('Tansaction: ' + recObj.getValue({fieldId: 'tranid'}))
        log.debug('runtime.executionContext: ' + runtime.executionContext)///remove after debug
        var isConnectedField = sublist.getField({id: 'custcol_isconnected'});//this is line 25
        var connectedPoField = sublist.getField({id: 'custcol_connected_po'});
```

Here is the log:

DEBUG | runtime.executionContext: USERINTERFACE

SYSTEM | org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getField" of null (/SuiteScripts/rei_userEvent_so.js#25)
JS_EXCEPTION

Any Insight into why this may be happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd need to know a little more about what transaction types you've deployed this against but you mention multiple types. Simple answer is that not all transactions have an `items` sublist.

e.g. neither vendorbill nor deposit have an item sublist

You could short circuit this like:

```js
var sublist = form.getSublist({
  id : 'item'
});

if(!sublist) return; // not one of the transactions of interest
```

There may also be types of events where the sublist isn't available. You're code doesn't show filtering for type. You could try something like this just before you reference the form. I've had some strange UserEvent issues when I don't do filter for type:

```js
if (context.type != ctx.UserEventType.VIEW && context.type != ctx.UserEventType.EDIT && context.type != ctx.UserEventType.CREATE) return;
```

Comment: The only transaction type this is deployed against is the sales order and the fields only show on sales order forms.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the fields are there. It's the sublist that's blank/null

Comment: Ok, this is good to know. I used your solution and I have stop receiving the error and there does not appear to be any other issues. Accepted answer, once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Another Note, I do use context type later in the code however I opted to write these variables outside the if (context) since I am mostly showing and hiding fields based on context and did not want to repeat the code in each statement.